# Unit-test login with passport.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, passport.js

I'm trying to test my local-login. I've implemented with `passport.js`, following its guide and following this [MEAN](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) skeleton.

I'm pretty sure that the implementation is fine, but there is something wrong with the test that always fails authentication.

**If authentication fails it should be redirect to "/signin"
if authentication is correct it should be go to "/"**

But when I test, the authentication always fails.

This is *routes.js*:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport, auth) {
    var users = require('../app/controllers/users');
    app.get('/signin', users.signin);

    app.post('/users/session', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/signin',
        failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.'
    }), users.session);

    var index = require('../app/controllers/index');
    app.get('/', index.render);
```

*passport.js*:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
User = mongoose.model('User'),
config = require('./config');


module.exports = function(passport) {
    //Serialize sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findOne({
            _id: id
        }, '-salt -hashed_password', function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    //Use local strategy
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password'
        },
        function(email, password, done) {
            User.findOne({
                email: email
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Unknown user'
                    });
                }
                if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Invalid password'
                    });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
}
```

and test: *api.js*:

```
var User, app, mongoose, request, server, should, user;

should   = require("should");
app      = require("../server");
mongoose = require("mongoose");
User     = mongoose.model("User");
request  = require("supertest");
server   = request.agent("http://localhost:3000");

describe("<Unit Test>", function() {
  return describe("API User:", function() {
    before(function(done) {
      user = new User({
        email    : "user@user.com",
        firstName: "Full Name",
        lastName : "Last Name",
        password : "pass11"
      });
      user.save();
      return done();
    });
    describe("Authentication", function() {
      return it("Local login", function(done) {
        return server.post("/users/session").send({
          email   : "user@user.com",
          password: "pass11"
        }).end(function(err, res) {
          res.headers.location.should.have.equal("/");
          return done();
        });
      });
    });
    return after(function(done) {
      User.remove().exec();
      return done();
    });
  });
});
```

This is what the terminal displays:

```
<Unit Test>
    API User:
      Authentication
        1) Local login


  0 passing (24ms)
  1 failing

  1) <Unit Test> API User: Authentication Local login:

      actual expected

      /signin
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm trying using this code and work as expected

```
var User, app, mongoose, request, server, should, user, agent;

should   = require("should");
app      = require("../server");
mongoose = require("mongoose");
User     = mongoose.model("User");
request  = require("supertest");
agent = request.agent(app)

describe('User', function () {
  before(function(done) {
      user = new User({
        email    : "user@user.com",
        firstName: "Full Name",
        lastName : "Last Name",
        password : "pass11"
      });
      user.save(done)
    });
  describe('Login test', function () {
      it('should redirect to /', function (done) {
        agent
        .post('/users/session')
        .field('email', 'user@user.com')
        .field('password', 'pass11')
        .expect('Location','/')
        .end(done)
      })

  after(function(done) {
      User.remove().exec();
      return done();
    });

})
})
```

for more reference check this [test-user](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/test/test-users.js)

here my screenshot
[image]

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot! My problem was in the `server= request.agent("http://localhost:3000");`. I have put `server = request.agent(app);` and that's all! ;)

Comment: I have a very similar login and authentication. I am trying to adapt this code for my needs. For some reason the test user is not created in my DB. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: The unit testing above just for testing. The process are insert new user, check login test, then delete user after test. so after test complete the user is supposed to be deleted.